# Как лучше всего организовать обработку клиентов в потоках?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Имеется Web-сервер, хочу добавлять клиентов в потоки, но ограничивать их число (например, не больше 10 потоков).

Отсюда задача: как приходит новый клиент, создавать для него поток, если все потоки заняты, то ожидать освобождение любого потока.

Сейчас мне в голову приходит только создать контейнер (не определился с выбором какой именно) и вставлять в него новые потоки, потом запускать их.
Если потоков больше 10, то ожидать освобождения одного из них.

Ещё хотел спросить: лучше ли убивать и создавать потоки (передавать в метод самого потока ссылку на этот поток, чтобы он завершал себя и удалял из контейнера) или держать их всегда живыми?

Comment: Всегда живыми. Вам нужна реализация thread pool, наверняка в том же бусте есть готовая.

Comment: Не уверен, что boost ее приняли, но в сети, оформленная для boost, существует библиотека как раз с реализацией thread pool.

Answer (score 3):

Нет смысла создавать/убивать потоки, так как это несет только проблемы (переносимость, скорость, обработка ошибок создания и проч.) и не несет никакого профита.

В любой ситуации, какова бы она ни была, вы можете оценить - а сколько памяти/процессора/других ресурсов вы реально готовы "пожертвовать" на обработку клиентов.
Допустим, вы готовы пожертвовать ресурсов на 10 потоков. Тогда оптимально будет запустить сразу 10 потоков, которые будут работать, когда есть работа, и спать, когда нету.

Все дальнейшее (что делать с новым клиентом, как обрабатывать существующих) уже зависит от архитектуры вашего сервера.

Comment: А есть ли смысл ставить кол-во потоков больше, чем ядер процессора?

Comment: @Fangog, при определенных обстоятельствах - да. Какие именно это обстоятельства, вопрос не совсем тривиальный для обсуждения в комментариях. Простой пример: если код ваших потоков может иногда выполнять долгие тяжелые синхронные операции, блокируясь в этих операциях, то тупое увеличение количества потоков такую систему ускорит.